# What does ARB mean in the opengl functions?

Tags: opengl

This should be easy one, I just haven't found any reference to that.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

ARB stands for ["Architecture Review Board"](http://www.opengl.org/about/arb/)

OpenGL extensions start their life as vendor specific extensions, then they may be eventually reworked as a stamped ARB and finally they might enter the core specification in a future release: see [All About OpenGL Extensions](http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/OGLextensions/).